# PHP Interfaces are used in Dependency Injections, how then?

Tags: php, interface, dependency-injection

I have seen the following code:

```
class LoginAuth
{

   function __construct(AuthInterface $auth)
   {
      $this->auth = $auth;
   }

   function userLogin ($credits)
   {
      return $this->auth->login($credits);
   }

}
```

My Question is that Interfaces as described by PHP is:

```
 Object interfaces allow you to create code which specifies which methods a class must
 implement, without having to define how these methods are handled.
```

So, we see that interfaces are not used to define an internal logic of a [class'] controller, they just allow for definition of which methods should be implemented by a certain class.

How then it could be possible that, an interface which does not contain any actual logic inside the methods, be deployed. I mean, the method `login()` which is a member of `auth()` class is defined in an interface:

```
interface AuthInterface ()
{ 
   function login($credits){}
}
```

Then how such signature could be used (as it is used in the main example)?

Comment: The methods of the `interfaces` are to be implemented when you use the `implements` keyword, until then it is not necessary.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you referring to the purpose of an interface?

Comment: I'm referring to the purpose of interface and why it is no used directly used in here? in a place other than class implementation